# pyspark code on EMR with non-default spark.executor.memory setting not taking effect?

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

So, I am trying to run my spark code on EMR with three m4.2xlarge instances (one master and 2 core nodes).

Each machine has 32GB memory. I keep running into this error:

```
16/07/17 23:32:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 41, ip-172-31-55-189.ec2.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.8 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

To boost memory, I am using the following `conf` settings in my Spark code before creating the `SparkContext`.

```
conf.set('spark.executor.instances', 2)
conf.set('spark.executor.cores', 2)
conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '12g')
conf.set('spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead', '0.2')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Yet, I still get the same error indicating that the increased memory per executor has not taken effect. Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to have the 32GB memory split between two tasks on each core instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually set the `spark.executor.memory` successfully. The way Spark calculates the storage memory is roughly `.54 * spark.executor.memory`, which is about 5.5g in your case.

C.f., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191547/spark-executor-memory-cut-to-1-2)

Also, it seems your value for `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is wrong. It is a number in mb so `0.2` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the 'fraction' setting is something different. This also takes a numeric value rather than a '8g' type string in some other options. Strange inconsistencies in the APIs. When I modified it it a numeric 8192 value, things worked.